# Haxe IE9 xmlHTTPrequest issue

Tags: html, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-9, haxe

I'm having problems displaying my Haxe game in IE9. It's actually not displaying at all. We tracked down the issue inside the compiled JS file for Haxe and found out that the problem is within the haxe.HTTP API.

There are certain things that need to be checked and done for IE9 to work with xmlhttprequests. These things were not done in the Haxe API.

This is the http class without my fix:

```
                this.url = url;
                this.headers = new List();
                this.params = new List();
                this.async = true;
            };
            $hxClasses["haxe.Http"] = haxe.Http;
            haxe.Http.__name__ = ["haxe","Http"];
            haxe.Http.prototype = {
                setParameter: function(param,value) {
                    this.params = Lambda.filter(this.params,function(p) {
                        return p.param != param;
                    });
                    this.params.push({ param : param, value : value});
                    return this;
                }
                ,request: function(post) {
                    var me = this;
                    me.responseData = null;
                    var r = this.req = js.Browser.createXMLHttpRequest();
                    var onreadystatechange = function(_) {
                        if(r.readyState != 4) return;
                        var s;
                        try {
                            s = r.status;
                        } catch( e ) {
                            s = null;
                        }
                        if(s == undefined) s = null;
                        if(s != null) me.onStatus(s);
                        if(s != null && s >= 200 && s < 400) {
                            me.req = null;
                            me.onData(me.responseData = r.responseText);
                        } else if(s == null) {
                            me.req = null;
                            me.onError("Failed to connect or resolve host");
                        } else switch(s) {
                        case 12029:
                            me.req = null;
                            me.onError("Failed to connect to host");
                            break;
                        case 12007:
                            me.req = null;
                            me.onError("Unknown host");
                            break;
                        default:
                            me.req = null;
                            me.responseData = r.responseText;
                            me.onError("Http Error #" + r.status);
                        }
                    };
                    if(this.async) r.onreadystatechange = onreadystatechange;
                    var uri = this.postData;
                    if(uri != null) post = true; else {
                        var $it0 = this.params.iterator();
                        while( $it0.hasNext() ) {
                            var p = $it0.next();
                            if(uri == null) uri = ""; else uri += "&";
                            uri += encodeURIComponent(p.param) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(p.value);
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        if(post) r.open("POST",this.url,this.async); else if(uri != null) {
                            var question = this.url.split("?").length <= 1;
                            r.open("GET",this.url + (question?"?":"&") + uri,this.async);
                            uri = null;
                        } else r.open("GET",this.url,this.async);
                    } catch( e1 ) {
                        me.req = null;
                        this.onError(e1.toString());
                        return;
                    }
                    if(!Lambda.exists(this.headers,function(h) {
                        return h.header == "Content-Type";
                    }) && post && this.postData == null) r.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    var $it1 = this.headers.iterator();
                    while( $it1.hasNext() ) {
                        var h1 = $it1.next();
                        r.setRequestHeader(h1.header,h1.value);
                    }
                    r.send(uri);
                    if(!this.async) onreadystatechange(null);
                }
                ,onData: function(data) {
                }
                ,onError: function(msg) {
                }
                ,onStatus: function(status) {
                }
                ,__class__: haxe.Http
            };
```

and this is the code WITH the fix:

```
            haxe.Http = function(url) {
                this.url = url;
                this.headers = new List();
                this.params = new List();
                this.async = true;
            };
            $hxClasses["haxe.Http"] = haxe.Http;
            haxe.Http.__name__ = ["haxe","Http"];
            haxe.Http.prototype = {
                setParameter: function(param,value) {
                    this.params = Lambda.filter(this.params,function(p) {
                        return p.param != param;
                    });
                    this.params.push({ param : param, value : value});
                    return this;
                }
                ,request: function(post) {
                    var me = this;
                    me.responseData = null;
                    var r = this.req = js.Browser.createXMLHttpRequest();
                    var onreadystatechange = function(_) {
                    console.log('in onreadystatechange function');
                        //if(r.readyState != 4) return;
                        console.log(r.responseText);
                        console.log('r.status: ' + r.status);
                        me.req = null;
                        me.onData(me.responseData = r.responseText);
                    };
                    if(typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
                        console.log('XDomainRequest');
                        r.onload = onreadystatechange;
                    }
                    var uri = this.postData;

                    try {
                        console.log('calling r.open with url: ' + this.url);
                        r.open("GET",this.url);
                    } catch( e1 ) {
                        me.req = null;
                        this.onError(e1.toString());
                        return;
                    }

                            //r.send(uri);
                    //do it, wrapped in timeout to fix ie9
                     setTimeout(function () {
                           r.send();
                        }, 0);
                    //if(!this.async) onreadystatechange(null);

                }
                ,onData: function(data) {
                }
                ,onError: function(msg) {
                }
                ,onStatus: function(status) {
                }
                ,__class__: haxe.Http
            };
```

Note that this only implements the IE9 fix without doing the if statements to keep support for other browsers. But it's really easy. the IF statement is simply

```
if(typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") return new XDomainRequest();
```

Basically, I know what the issue is, I just have no idea how I can change these things within the core of Haxe itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/pull/3449

BAM! Got it working in a local version of my haxe. Fixed for all browsers and sent a pull request. :D

Answer (score 0):

Good job on this one!
You have to contact the Haxe mailing list directly, most thinking heads are over there rather than here :)

https://groups.google.com/d/forum/haxelang